# Get document object from a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Let's assume I have a jQuery object of a DIV element in body. I'd like to obtain document object by traversing. Can it be possible ?

Note: window.document is not a option in my case.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess so, walking from parent to parent... But I *think* every DOM element has a reference to its document anyway somewhere, let me check

Answer (score 130, accepted):

[`element.ownerDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ownerDocument) will give you a reference to the document to which any DOM element belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `document` object is the parent of the `<HTML>` element (at least in Firefox).  Find it like this:

```
function FindDoc(el) {
    while(el.parentNode) {
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
}
```

Comment: That would be slower than directly accessing it. Why not try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338224/how-do-i-get-the-window-object-from-the-document-object

Answer (score 0):

firstElementChild
The first child that is an element node 
[Traversal module.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/traversal.html#firstElementChild)