# Access JavaScript global variables from VBA while scraping

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am writing a macro in VBA for Excel that examines a page and I need to extract a variable that is set within a script in the HTML. In the macro, I create an IE object thusly:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Pages in the target website all have the following script which defines a variable called `digitalData.page.pageName`. Here is a snippet of HTML:

```
<script>
var digitalData = '';
function init() {
digitalData = {
  "user": {
    "userLoginState": "guest",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userEmployeeName": "",
    "userBirthday": "",
    "userGender": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userID": "",
    "LRUserID": "",
    "userEmployeeID": "",
    "userDWID": "",
    "userSessionId": "BYTEzHFAdLrPoPPOlTPGWvlBjCx54jjEyB8="
  },
  "page": {
    "pageName": "en_us:plp:men:clothing:Casual Shirts",
    "pageType": "plp",
    "pageGender": "men",
    "pageLocale": "us",
    "pageRedirected": "no",
    "pageJSErrorCount": "3",
    "pageLevel1": "men",
    "pageLevel2": "men/clothing",
    "pageLevel3": "men/clothing/Casual Shirts",
    "pageLevel4": "men/clothing/Casual Shirts",
    "pageHierarchy": "men/clothing/Casual Shirts"
  },
```

If I open a page from this site in Chrome and inspect it, I can type the variable name in the console and it will return the value but I can't seem to access the variable from IE using VBA like this:

```
inspectLink(i, 1) = objIE.digitalData.page.pageName
```

In this case, I would like to find `en_us:plp:men:clothing:Casual Shirts` in `inspectLink(i, 1)` but instead I get `Runtime error '438' Object doesn't support the property or method`.

```
Dim inspectCat(4) As String
inspectCat(0) = "webcat=men"
inspectCat(1) = "webcat=women"
inspectCat(2) = "webcat=kids"
inspectCat(3) = "webcat=baby"
inspectCat(4) = "webcat=home"

Dim targetSearchCount as Integer
Dim failedSearchCount as Integer
targetSearchCount=0
failedSearchCount=0

REM New Code - DOES NOT WORK cannot access pageName this way
REM if digitalData.page.pageName has en_us: in it, then it's our target
REM if it has failedSearchResult in it, then report to web dev team
REM syntax might be objIE.Document.digitalData.page.pageName

REM inspectLink(i, 1) = objIE.digitalData.page.pageName
REM MsgBox inspectLink(i, 1)
REM if inStr(objIE.digitalData.page.pageName, "en_us:") then targetSearchCount=targetSearchCount+1 endif
REM if inStr(objIE.digitalData.page.pageName, "failed_Search_Result") then failedSearchCount=failedSearchCount+1 endif
REM End New Code

REM Begin Old Code - WORKS BUT "dublicate" MAY NOT BE RELIABLE OVER TIME
REM 
Set pageNameDubs = objIE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("page-Name-dublicate")
'MsgBox pageNameDubs(0).Value
For Each pageName In pageNameDubs
'    If InStr(pageName.innertext, "en_us:") > 0 Then   
        inspectLink(i, 1) = pageName.Value
'    End If
Next
REM End Old Code
```

Comment: What's `inspectLink`?  Are the objects declared? How?  Can't troubleshooting without seeing the what you're seeing.  Please add your VBA to the question..  See [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Done.

Comment: Jerome, have you had a chance to try out my answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I've been swamped with other problems. The "dublicate" query works for now so improving it is not at the top of the priority list. I'll certainly let you know when I try to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting one.  This answer is specifically about accessing `digitalData.page.pageName`.  In the code below, everything between `VVV` and `^^^` does that, based on a document that's already loaded.  You can integrate that part into your existing code.

In the Developer Console, this is as simple as `digitalData.page.pageName`, or, equivalently, `document.defaultView.digitalData.page.pageName` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338472/2877364)).  You can get `document.defaultView` in Excel VBA, but I can't figure out how to access JavaScript globals from that object.  Instead, I did it through the DOM.  The below sample works for me.

#### Code

First, make sure you have added references to Microsoft Internet Controls and to Microsoft HTML Object Library.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public Sub GetResult()
    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    ' Load the page with the target data
    With objIE
        .navigate "http://cxw42.github.io/49290039.html?buster=1"
        ' Cache buster thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851824/how-long-does-it-take-for-github-page-to-show-changes-after-changing-index-html#comment69647442_24871850
        ' by https://stackoverflow.com/users/185973/joel-glovier
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set doc = objIE.document

    ' VVVVVVVVVVVVVV

    Dim win As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2
    Set win = doc.defaultView

    ' Should be able to directly access win.digitalData, but I can't get that to work.
    ' Instead, access the data indirectly

    Dim uniqueid As String
    uniqueid = "id_" & Format(Now, "%yyyy%mm%dd%hh%nn%ss")
    Dim code As String
    code = "(function(){var x = document.createElement('p'); x.id='" & uniqueid & "'; x.innerText=digitalData.page.pageName; document.body.appendChild(x); })()"
        ' Copy digitalData.page.pageName into the DOM
    win.execScript code, "JavaScript"

    Dim pageName As String
    Dim node
    Set node = doc.getElementById(uniqueid)     ' Get the new DOM node
    pageName = node.innerText

    ' Clean up
    doc.getElementsByTagName("body").Item(0).RemoveChild node

    ' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

    ' Now do whatever you want with pageName.
    Debug.Print pageName
End Sub
```

#### Explanation

The magic is in `code` and `win.execScript`.  `code` is a JavaScript oneliner that creates a new `<p>` element and copies `digitalData.page.pageName` into it.  `win.execScript` runs that JavaScript in the context of the page, thereby creating the new node.  The node has a `uniqueid` (well, probably unique) that we can use to find it once it's been created.  Then we can pull the result out of the `innerText` of that paragraph.

#### Thanks to

- [`document.defaultView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338472/2877364)
- [Scraping using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27069914/2877364)
- [Github Pages cache-busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851824/how-long-does-it-take-for-github-page-to-show-changes-after-changing-index-html#comment69647442_24871850)
- [The importance of early binding](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30854990#30854990) (read it!)